# Find a 2x2 matrix, not the identity, s.t. A^4 = I

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As stated. I'm not sure where to start. I've been looking at matrices if the determinant = 1,-1, but that has been clearly the wrong way to go about this. Any tips?

Comment: Try a rotation matrix

Comment: make a matrix that means a rotation of $90^\circ$ in the plane

Comment: Well, you're looking in the right place -- the matrix you seek must have determinant $\pm 1$. But try thinking of matrices as representing transformations --- is there some operation you can do four times and have it be the same as doing nothing?

Comment: OH wow. Thanks a ton. Sometimes you get so caught up in the semantics and equations, you forget to just visualize it sometimes. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Think about rotation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the diagonal matrix
$$
D=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Note that $D^4=I$.

Now, if $P$ is invertible, then $A=PDP^{-1}$ satisfies
$$
A^4=PD^4P^{-1}=PIP^{-1}=PP^{-1}=I
$$
For instance, taking
$$
P=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 5 \\
2 & 11
\end{array}\right]
$$
gives
$$
A
=\overset{P}{\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 5 \\
2 & 11
\end{array}\right]}\overset{D}{\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right]}\overset{P^{-1}}{\left[\begin{array}{rr}
11 & -5 \\
-2 & 1
\end{array}\right]}=\left[\begin{array}{rr}
21 & -10 \\
44 & -21
\end{array}\right]
$$